# ruby on rails:about mediaelement_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mediaelement

I'm useing the mediaelement_rails gem. What I do is just follow the document to install.

```
gem "mediaelement_rails"
```

then Load the Mediaelement Javascript in my application.js:

```
//= require mediaelement_rails
```

finally Load the Mediaelement CSS in application.css:

```
 /*
  *= require mediaelement_rails
  * and optionally:
  *= require mediaelement_rails/mejs-skins
  */
```

when I run my app,It got wrong:

```
couldn't find file 'mediaelement_rails'
(in /home/kgtong/rail/test_1/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:15)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you run bundle install?

Comment: Thanks. I restart the server and it works. The audio appears, but when I click button, nothing happens. What's the matter?